# Is it possible to add "Prefixes" before namesers?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-zone, delegation

I've been looking at [this website](http://nameserver.io/) where you enter an input string and you get an output `"some_random_string.1.nameserver.io"`.

Now, I'm not sure if this is possible for any nameserver. Say you have `ns1.somedomain.com`, if you add any random string before that, will this impact DNS resolution in any way? Or is this just ignored?

Answer (score 1):

**No.** [Domain Name System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) doesn't work that way at all.

This nameserver.io is a specific service that

> provides a service to easily redirect your domains at the nameserver
>   level. Simply enter where you want the domains to redirect, and we
>   will provide you with the nameserver addresses to set for your
>   domains.

The prefix is formed this way:

> To get the nameserver addresses, we Base32 encode the redirect url, do
>   this to it: `(base32Str.replace(/=/g,'').match(/.{1,30}/g) || []).join('.');` and then prepend the result to `.1.NAMERSERVER.IO` and
>   `.2.NAMERSERVER.IO`

(The information on these quotes was behind the [learn more](http://nameserver.io/#one) button on nameserver.io.)